# Find if/where a function is used

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-functions

After deprecating a function, we would like to do some cleaning and delete de function to avoid any user using it in the future. Is there a way to find if it used? And if so where is it used?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are no current tracking mechanisms to find out where a deprecated function is being used and remove it to avoid future usage. I recommend submitting this as a feature request through Palantir support.

Edit: There is a on beta feature where you can navigate to your function in the ontology-metadata-app and see "usage history". This will not show all the apps that are configured to use your function, but will show if the function has been called recently. I believe this will hit all customers soon